# Center view between two views, centered view takes space of those two views when it is below them

Tags: android, layout

I have to do something like this:

There is a `TextView` on the left, an `Add` button on the right, when user clicks `Add`, he can choose from the list of items, and each item will be rendered as a view (`ImageButton` for example), with background and listener,...

Here is how the layout looks like when just a few items are selected

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|          |                          |     |
| TextView | View View View View      |  +  |
|----------|                          |-----|
|                                           |
```

But when a lot of items are selected I have to display them like this:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|          |                          |     |
| TextView | View View View View View |  +  |
|----------|                          |-----|
| View View View View View View View View   |
|                                           |
| View View View                            |
|                                           |
```

I can put all the views inside a linear layout and make it center between the `TextView` and the `Button`, but the problem is, when the views are below the `TextView` and the `Button`, they have to take all the space of those two views as well

Any help would be appreciated